# Python tkinter package not functioning properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm just starting with tkinter, not even running or preparing complex GUI apps, I have used this simple commands on other servers and it has worked perfectly, so the problem is probably in my installation.

My Linux version is 18.04 my python version is 3.6.5
.I have tried connecting from ssh, tried connecting from windows putty ( itś a remote server).

this is the code I try  to execute:

```
from tkinter import * 
potato = Tk()
potato.mainloop()
```

This is the error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1a8e1fdc2509> in <module>()
      1 from tkinter import *
----> 2 potato = Tk()
      3 potato.mainloop()

/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py in __init__(self, screenName, baseName, className, useTk, sync, use)
   2018                 baseName = baseName + ext
   2019         interactive = 0
-> 2020         self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
   2021         if useTk:
   2022             self._loadtk()



TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

I'm kind of a noob, so please tell me any missing information you might need.

Comment: you need to have x forwarding in putty: http://ocean.stanford.edu/courses/ESS141/PuTTY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works properly don't worry about it.

In this case the error you are getting (`no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable`) is related to your SSH connection due to that the server is not able to find a display where to render your program.

If you want to use PuTTY and view the tkinter app in your windows machine (run a X server) you will need to specify that in the PuTTY configuration beforehand. In order to do that you just have to enable the X11 forwarding (in Connection > SSH > X11 > Enable X11 forwarding).

Comment: But the same error also happens when I connect from a linux desktop computer, it happens in both.  Does that mean I need to enable that x11 fowarding in both?

Comment: @brandata yes, it is the same on linux or mac os. You will need to enable X11 forwarding over the SSH connection independently of the platform. With the `ssh` command on linux this is done with the `-X` option.

Comment: solved, thank you kind sir, may the gods show you favor